# Find A of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Find  $$(2A)^T = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&-1\\2&3\end{array}\right]^{-1}$$

My solution

$$2A^T = \left[\begin{array}{cc}3&-2\\1&1\end{array}\right] = \frac12\left[\begin{array}{cc}3&-2\\1&1\end{array}\right], A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}3&-2\\1&1\end{array}\right]$$

Apparently this is completely wrong and the answer is

$$\frac{1}{10}\left[\begin{array}{cc}3&-2\\1&1\end{array}\right]$$ I do not understand where they got the $1/10$.

Answer (score 2):

Determinant = ad - bc = (3 $\times$ 1) - (-2 $\times$ 1) = 5

The inverse of the matrix = $\frac{1}{determinant}$adj(matrix) = $\frac {1}{5}$adj(matrix)

Bring the 2 over, it becomes $\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: Oh i see thanks. What if the question differed by $$(2A)^-1 = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&-1\\2&3\end{array}\right]$$, Would i still do the determinant if i bring over the inverse?

Comment: Hint:  $(B^{-1})^{-1} = B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You may have forgotten to include the determinant
$$\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&-1\\2&3\end{array}\right]$$
in your computation.